# Ubuntu 16.04 System crash when out of RAM

Tags: 16.04, swap, memory-usage, cryptswap

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10. I experienced crashes (system not responding, requiring a power off) every time I was **running out of physical memory** (using up all the RAM).

Comment: I also experience crashes (system not responding or very slowly, e.g. I can move the mouse cursor and exited firefox but it took me five minutes) since I removed my swap partition from the logical volume. Is there no way to block the usage of a progam that wants to add more usage to the RAM than is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I have switched to a **standard swap** instead of **cryptswap** using [1]. I did not experienced the issue again. I believe that my cryptswap partition was not being used when the physical memory was 100% used and the system would just crash.

[1] https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/29155